# Rotating zombies to face player

Tags: java, trigonometry, degrees

I am trying to rotate a horde of zombies to face a player. I have been trying to figure it out myself for some time but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using the following code currently to rotate zombies:

```
public void calculateAngle() {
        double theta = 0.0d;
        for(Zombie zombie : entities) {
            double a = zombie.getX() - player.getX(); 
            double b = zombie.getY() - player.getY();
            double c = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));

            if(zombie.getX() > player.getX() && zombie.getY() > player.getY())
                theta = Math.sin(b / c) + 90;
            else if(zombie.getX() < player.getX() && zombie.getY() > player.getY())
                theta = Math.sin(b / a) - 60;
            else if(zombie.getX() > player.getX() && zombie.getY() < player.getY())
                theta = Math.sin(a / c);
            else
                theta = Math.sin(a / c);
            zombie.setDegrees(theta);
        }
    }
```

I tried using the atan2 function that people have suggested but it never worked for me. I know the position of the zombies and the position of the player. How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I read the comments and what Thomas said works when implemented into my code. The updated code can be found below:

```
public void calculateAngle() {
        float theta = 0.0f;
        for(Zombie zombie : entities) {
            float a = zombie.getX() - player.getX() - 40; 
            float b = zombie.getMidpointY() - 10 - player.getY() - 10;

            theta = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(b, a)) + 90;
            zombie.setDegrees(theta);
        }
    }
```

The value changes such as - 40 and - 10 is used to adjust the x and y position so the zombies are facing the player correctly. To rotate the images themselves I am using AffineTransform with the .rotate(theta, x, y) method. I don't exactly know why using the Math.atan2() method did not work originally with my code but it works now. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: So the actual problem is how to correctly calculate `theta`? Or does the rotation itself have problems as well?

Comment: You'd normally calculate the rotation angle by getting the angle between the direction vector (zombie to player) and some base vector (e.g. the x-axis). For the basics have a look [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/) and note that libraries often return the angle in radians so if you want degrees you need to convert that (the libs normally have methods for that too). Further note that your `a` and `b` currently describe the direction from the player to the zombie which might produce an angle that is off by 180 degrees.

Comment: In addition to my comment above `Math.atan2()` should work if used correctly. Try `Math.toDegrees( Math.atan2( b ,a ) )` and note that you'll get the angle in the range -180 to +180 degrees and that angle is the angle between that vector and the x-axis. Thus depending on what you based your rotation angle on you might have to adjust the result by some multiple of 90 degrees (e.g. if it should be relative to the y-axis you might have to subtract or add 90 degrees).

Answer (score 2):

`sin` function expects degrees as input and its result is always within `[-1..1]`, you cannot calculate degrees using it.